# Why do 'había' and 'habrá' not have trailing 'i/y's?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, etimología

Modern Spanish's *hay* has the following etymology:

> From ha, third-person singular present of haber ‎(“to have”), + i, from Latin ibī ‎(“there”).

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hay#Spanish))

However, the other tenses' equivalent of *hay*, such as *'había'* and *'habrá'*, have no such trailing 'y' or 'i'.

Why is this, do they have separate etymologies?

Comment: If you keep asking questions like this one, I'll be your fan forever.

Comment: :) I've been learning Spanish and I'm very interested in Spanish Language and its etymology

Comment: I have read somewhere that the _-i_ from _ibi_ is also present in _doy, soy_ and _voy_, but I could not confirm it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45845/discussion-between-bladorthinthegrey-and-carlos-alejo).

Comment: Perhaps it's the same reason that "Rey" (King) used to be spelled like "Rei", but that word "Rei" in plural was "Reyes" (and still is).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with CarlosAlejo with regard to something being *there* in the present tense. I found further reference about the origin of the verb and the modifications it suffered in the interesting volume [*Morfología del verbo castellano*](https://archive.org/details/morfologadelver00lancgoog) by Rufino Lanchetas, which was published in 1897 but is nevertheless full of useful information. Regarding the verb *haber* it says, among other things, [this](https://archive.org/stream/morfologadelver00lancgoog#page/n203/mode/2up):

> **Indicative present.— First person.—** In relation with its Latin origin
>   *habeo* and the uniformity of the radical, and according
>   to the seventh phonetic rule, it should be *habo*. This form is not
>   found in any period in the history of Spanish , and we should look
>   elsewhere to expain it. The first person, *habeo*, as well as Subjunctive
>   *habeam* and *habeas* had, from the time of the Gracchi, the *e* in the
>   formative suffix changed into an *i*, thus instead of *habeas* and
>   *habeat* we find *habias* and *habiat* [...] So [...] the Latin form
>   *habeo* first became *habio*. With the *b* lost as per the sixth phonetic
>   rule, we should have got *haio*, as in *habias* = *hayas*. This form
>   is likewise not to be found in Neo-Latin languages — we can only say
>   that for reasons unknown the *o* was dropped, thus giving us
>   *hai*, a form that is found in Provençal, French and Asturian.
>   *Hai* became *hei*, as retained in Portuguese and Galician. Spanish went
>   one step beyond and, as in *sei* = *sé* and *amei* = *amé*, went through
>   *hei* = * *hee* and came from a very early time to establish *he* both in
>   the present tense as well as in the future derived from it. Phonetic
>   process: *habeo*, *habio*, * *haio*, *hai*, *hei*, *hee*, *he*.
>
> ***Subjunctive.—*** Every form in this mood can be explained by the same process used for the first person of the Indicative present, with
>   the peculiarity that the forms in Subjunctive present were limited to the
>   loss of the *b* and the conversion of the palatal vowel *i*
>   into a consonant. Their phonetic process has been as follows:
>   *habeat*, *habiat*, *habia*, *haia*, *haya*, and the same in the other persons. The form *haya* is very old: *"Desto que ellos fablaron nos
>   parte non ayamos."* (*Poem of El Cid*.) [...]
>
> The Indicative third person singular present gets a paragogic *y* when
>   used as unipersonal [impersonal?] meaning "to exist" or "to have", e.g.
>   *"Hay Dios."* Its origin may be traced back to the 15th century when some
>   monosyllabic forms got the addition of the mentioned paragogic *y*, such as
>   *soy*, *voy*, *doy*. [Could this conflict with the etymology of *hay* as
>   *haber* + *ibi*?]
>
> **Second group: past imperfect (*había*, *habías*, *habíamos*, etc*) / future**   When forming these tenses based on the Infinitive, it would be
>   expected for them to be *haberé*, *habería*. We can sometimes find
>   these full forms in ancient documents [...] [b]ut the most usual form
>   at all times was the current one, with a syncope: *habré*, *habría*.
>   [...] This syncope can be explained in the same way as that in *sabré*
>   and *cabré*. It consists of the supression of the forming suffix *e*
>   by the accent in the final *e*, something helped by the former being
>   unstressed and the resulting consonant group *bre* being easy to
>   articulate. Portuguese and Galician retain the full form *haverei*,
>   *haverás*, etc.

Certainly a lot of time has passed since this was published and perhaps it would be wise not to take it as the absolute truth, but I found no newer sources as yet.

---

After some more googling, I found some more material:

The 1948 article [*Una pesquisa acerca del verbo haber*](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/04/TH_04_003_120_0.pdf), hosted at the Centro Virtual Cervantes, says that

> The phonetic evolution of this verb has been perfectly researched and
>   its evolutionary movement from the Latin form to the present Spanish
>   one can be traced step by step. There can be neither discussion nor
>   doubts about it, and it is enough to read Menéndez Pidal's *Gramática
>   histórica* to satisfy the curiosity of even the most exigent reader.

The article, a discussion of the impersonal use of *haber*, goes on to say:

> In the *Poem of El Cid* the verb is scarcely found accompanied of the
>   adverb *y* or *i* or *hi*, and sometimes without it, used as an
>   impersonal or unipersonal verb. In such a long poem it only appears a
>   couple of times:
>
> *Entre Minaya — e los buenos que* i ha [...]
>   *Todos eran ricos — quantos que allí* ha [...]
>
> And the classic example found in every explanation of the certainly scant history of the use of *haber* as an impersonal verb:
>
> *Tales* i a *que prenden — tales* i a *que non.*

I looked for Menéndez Pidal work and found another very old edition of the [*Manual elemental de gramática castellana*](https://archive.org/details/manualelementald00menuoft), which says in the [section concerning the Irregular present](https://archive.org/stream/manualelementald00menuoft#page/184/mode/2up):

> In the past, *habere* presented some forms derived from Classical
>   Latin *habes* (but not from the 1st person *habeo*) and *habet*:
>   "ave", "aves", "avemos", "avedes", "aven". But the ones that prevailed
>   were derived from a contraction this verb suffered in Vulgar Latin in
>   order to make its use as an auxiliary easier, in which the stressed
>   vowel and the suffix: 1st person *haio*, "heo" or "hey" (antiquated)
>   and "he"; 2nd person, *has*, "has"; 3rd person, *hat*, "ha", which
>   when joined with the adverb "y" gave the impersonal *hay*; 4th person,
>   *(hab)emus*, "hemos"; 5th person, *(hab)etis*, "hedes", "heis"; 6th person, *hant*, "han". These are the forms that prevailed, duplicating
>   the 4th person with "habemos" and reserving the 5th person for use as
>   an auxiliar ("amar-eis" and Classical "heis de estar", etc.), using
>   "habeis" for the other cases.
>   **Subjunctive.** Classical *habeam* is clearly reflected in Asturian dialectal *eba*, *ebas*, etc. The Vulgar Latin contraction *hajam*,
>   *-s*, *-t* is the one that gave the usual form "haya", "hayas", etc.
>   **Imperative.** *habe*, "ave", which was still used in Spanish Classics; "habed", not used very often nowadays.

Sadly, I do not have access to modern material such as Ralph Penny's *Gramática histórica del español*, and actually know very little about Spanish historical grammar, but it looks then like it is rather settled that the impersonal *hay* is indeed the fusion of *ha* plus an adverb derived from Latin *ibi* or *hic*. With regard to that, further searching led me to an article in the much more recent book [*Cuestiones de actualidad en la lengua española*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DiSjEvvmA7gC&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187#v=onepage&q&f=false) that says that

> The addition of -y in the 1st person Present in the irregular verbs
>   *dar*, *estar*, *ser* and *ir* is a topic of eternal discussion in Spanish historic morphology. There are at least four hypotheses about
>   its origin: analogy with the ancient form "hay", "hey" from *habeo*;
>   agglutination of a pronominal subject ("so yo" > "soy"); agglutination
>   of the old adverb "y" from *ibi/hic* as in "ha" + "y" > "hay"; and
>   addition of a paragogic vowel ("soe" > "soy").

---

From what I have been superficially looking at, not many scholars have tackled the question — one who did was Joel Rini in his book [*Exploring the Role of Morphology in the Evolution of Spanish*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U0Uqd56ZwDYC&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q&f=false), which has a section on "the *-y* of Spanish *hay*". Basically, he questions current theories and points out that the -y appears only in present tense and is a suffix instead of being in front of the verb, unlike in French, Catalan and Italian (*il y avait*, *hi havia*, *ci era*), and also gives examples in which the joined form *ay* is used together with the adverb *y*, such as

> Et daquel Jnfant Theseo que fue muy buen uaron & de muchos et muy
>   grandes fechos que fizo Egeo esse Rey de Athenas uos contaremos
>   adelant en sos logares de muchas & grandes razones que **ay y**
>   dellos. (Alfonso X, *General Estoria*)

He goes on to argue that the origin of *hay* might be found in the subjunctive *haya* and not in the addition of the adverb *y* to *ha*. On the other hand, he points out that researcher Érica C. García argued that

> [...] the agglutination of *y* occurred only in the present tense
>   because of the much higher frequency of the existential use of *haver*
>   in in this tense: "The reinterpretation of *aver* + *y* took place,
>   however, only in the Present Indicative — far and away the most
>   frequent tense for the existential use of the verb, especially in
>   spoken language."

A long article (in Spanish) about the state of the question of the final *y* ("Doy, estoy, hay, soy y voy: cinco monosílabos con una terminación extraparadigmática. Estado de la cuestión.") can be found in the book [*Estudios de historiografía lingüística*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BOCCectxyHUC&pg=PA307#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Fascinating! I wonder what the etymology of the paragogic *y* is, as that might link in to ibi. Nevertheless, it looks like it's not as straight forward as it first seemed.

Comment: You're doing a very good job! If you could just find some uses similar to the _i ha_ in _The Cid_, but in past or future tenses, to see why those tenses don't have the trailing _-i_, you could write some conclussions and definitely answer the question.

Comment: Your research is impeccable, but we had pretty much confirmed that *hay* comes from *ha + y* (whether that 'y' is paragogic or from 'ibi'). What I specifically want to know is *why* other tenses do not share such an addition. I would expect that it is due to *hay*'s unique etymology, but that is what I am asking.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Yes, now that that is clear for me (I had some doubts as I though Lanchetas appeared to deny that the *y* in *hay* meant "ibi") I think I now fully understand your question — Why Old Spanish felt the need to add an *y* in present *ha* but not in the other tenses' impersonals. From what I have been looking at, looks like the answer is "nobody really knows".

Comment: Hi @JMVanPelt. I'm interested in what you can bring to this, but, as of yet, you've not really answered the question; why do other tenses not share an addition of a 'y'?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey That is exactly the problem — as the last article I linked to says (which I confess not having read in full as it is quite learned stuff), most scholars seem to agree that _hay_ had an independent evolution from _soy_, _doy_, _estoy_ and _voy_, and that the _y_ comes from _ibi_; but the fact that the _y_ in _hay_ appears only in First person present tense is what made Rini question the idea that it came from the adverb _ibi_ and postulate its origin in subjunctive _aya_. So no one is completely sure.

Comment: Ok. We're going to have to wait for someone who can answer it then.

Answer (score 2):

I have two possible theories I can't prove, just from my own imagination.

Starting from the [etymology](http://www.nebrija.com/revista-linguistica/fundamento-teorico-de-un-modelo-para-trabajar-los-verbos-haber-estar-y-ser-en-el-aula-de-ele) of *hay*: *ha* + *hi* → "ha y" (literally *he has there*). The first theory is that other tenses also used the trailing *hi*, but only the present tense ended up incorporating the trail into the form and generating *ha i* and then *hay* because of the similarities in the pronunciation of the words. The other tenses just suppressed the trailing *hi* or simply didn't incorporate it because there was no cacophony. This could be from a similar (but not the same) [process](http://spanishetym.com/term/oy) that generated *soy, doy, estoy* and others.

The second theory is that if you think about it, you only can *know* that something is in a given place ("there") in the present tense. You are seeing an object there and thus you can say *there is* (*ha hi*). In other tenses, e.g. *había, hubo, habrá*, you cannot be sure that the object was (or will be) there, so you couldn't say *había hi* or *habrá hi*.

I'm sorry I can't prove these theories, but I hope this will give an starting point to investigate further. Nonetheless, if I discover something else I'll come back and add it here.

Another clue: this is written in the *Cantar de mio Cid* (circa 1200):

> Catando estan a Myo Çid **quantos ha en la cort**,
>
> a la barba que auie luenga e presa con el cordon.

So back then you could say "ha" in the sense of the nowadays "hay", so the creation of the latter must have happened after that.

Comment: Interesting! I'll add in some references for the first theory, since we talked about that before.