# Why was the word for king 'rei' changed to 'rey'?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, topónimos

The Spanish word '*rey*' used to be spelt *rei* (as it still is in some old place names, e.g. [Plaça del Rei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pla%C3%A7a_del_Rei)).

Why did it change from one spelling to another?

Comment: From the [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=GcK2qQ2PBD61VSDUOs#5b): "[Se usa *y*] Cuando el sonido /i/ va en posición final de palabra y está precedido de otra vocal con la que forma diptongo, o de dos con las que forma triptongo: *muy, Uruguay*".

Comment: Have you been recently in Catalonia, right? :-)

Comment: Also note that there are not Spanish words ending in an unstressed [i] sound that are spelling with a terminal -i

Comment: Note you can see the origin of each street in Barcelona using their _nomenclàtor_ page. For [Plaça del Rei](http://w10.bcn.cat/APPS/nomenclator/ficha.do?codic=280600&idioma=2) we read that it was previously called _Plaza del Rey_, as places used to be officially in Spanish for many years.

Answer (score 6):

The *rei* spelling occurs in many Western Romance languages, but not in Castilian. The most ancient epic poem that remains to us in Old Spanish, *El Cantar de mio Çid*, notably has these lines:

> En yra del **rey** Alffonsso yo sere metido.
>   Si con uusco escapo sano o biuo
>   Aun çerca o tarde el **rey** querer me ha por amigo;
>   Si non quanto dexo no lo pre**ç**io un figo.
>   Ffablo Myo **Ç**id, el que en buen ora **ç**inxo espada:
>   Martin Antolinez, sodes ardida lan**ç**a:
>   Si yo biuo doblar uos he la soldada.

So *rey* was already spelled *rey* back in the Twelfth Century. The same is true of *plaza*, although other words did use the cedilla:

> Vio que entrellos e el castiello mucho auie grand **plaza**:
>   Mando tornar la senna, apriessa espoloneaua:
>   Ffirid los caualleros, todos sines dubdan**ç**a.

In contrast, it is now spelled *rei* in most other Iberian Romance, including in Asturian, Aragonese, Catalan, Galician, and Portuguese. Old Portuguese shared the *rey* spelling with Castilian, but that is no longer used today.

## Shifting Orthographies

Let’s remember that just as the Latin alphabet did not originally have the letter *v* (let alone *w*) but only *u*, so too did it have no letter *y* or *j*, only *i*. This meant that the *u* and *i* had to serve as both vowel and consonant.

Another important point is that there was no “fixed orthography” for many centuries. Different scribes spelled things differently, and no one thought anything of this. Notice how in El Cid above, you see the spellings *bi**u**o* for modern *vivo* and *m**y**o* for modern *mío*.

But even after the printing press, there was a great deal of variation. It was not so long ago that *San Isidro* was *San Ysidro*, and even the Castilian conjunction *y* was of old written *e* (as in Portuguese) and much more recently sometimes seen written as *i* (as in Catalan).

The website www.curiosidario.es “Curiosidario: Curiosidades de la Lengua Española” has an article on the [Historia de las letras](http://www.curiosidario.es/historia-de-las-letras-2/) in which they write:

> En el español antiguo la representación del sonido [i] la compartían la *i* (conocida como *i corta* o *media*), la llamada *baja* o *larga* (origen de nuestra j, como vimos en su apartado) y la *I* (conocida como alta). A su vez, la *i corta* o *media* y la *i baja* o *larga* (*j*) podían hacer oficio de consonantes, invadiendo el terreno de la *y*, con lo que la *y* se vio obligada a invadir el terreno vocálico de las otras. Debido a tal confusión, no era poco frecuente ver, por ejemplo, la palabra *viejo* escrita también *vieio* o *vjeio*; o *mayor* y *maIor*; o *sin* y *sjn*; o *isla* *eysla*; o *Pompeyo*, *Pompejo* y *Pompeio*. La solución empezó a darse con la aparición de la imprenta, pero tardó siglos en llegarse al acuerdo actual: *i* es vocal en todos los casos, *i griega* para la conjunción copulativa más para el sonido [*i*] al final de palabras que acaben en *-ái, -éi, -ói* y frecuentemente en *-úi* (*Uruguay, guiriguay, ley, doy, muy*).
>
> Así pues, desde 1726 la *y* se convirtió oficialmente en la conjunción copulativa del español, menos cuando la siguiente palabra empieza con *i*, en cuyo caso se sustituye por una *e*.

So for example, from Gonzalo de Berceo we read in *Milagros de Nuestra Sennora* from the thirteenth century, we read “nunqua varón en duenna metió ma**i**or querencia” for what we would now write “nunca varón en dueña metió ma**y**or querencia”.

There are many, many more examples of writing being different in past centuries than it is today. There are many reasons for this, however, with various stories to be be had for each.

Comment: *Rey* in plural is *reyes*. I don't know about Catalonian, but in Asturian and Portuguese, where king is also *rei*, the plural is *reis*. That follows normal plural rules: add s if ending in a vowel (i), add es if ending in a consonant. But now with many imported words, like *gay*, you now have to memorize (*gais*), so while rule is less useful in modern times, it can illustrate past rationales.

Comment: Why did *rey* become *rei* (and vice versa in other languages)?

Comment: @guifa I presume that is because *gay* is an import. Other words are regular, like *buey > bueyes*.  There is some dispute over *guay > ?guays* but I don’t know that word’s origin.

Comment: Plural of Rei in Catalan is *Reis*

Comment: Probably Catalan, Galician, Asturian, Portuges had not the same influcence of the arabic (800 years of influcence) than Castillian. In consequence they kept the essence of the Romance languages for longer than Castillian. Read about [History of the Catalan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Catalan). Special atention to the animated gift. Castillian had lot more foreign languages (influences) around than Catalan.

Comment: @Laiv I see no evidence that Arabic, which was never written in the Latin script in Al-Andalus, could possibly have influenced Castilian orthographic conventions of spelling word-final diphthongs and triphthongs with consonant *y* instead of with vocalic *i*. Neither do I see any evidence that Castilian orthography changed “more” or “faster” than the orthographies of other Spanish languages.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey El latín no tenía ninguna *y*: no es por nada que se llama *i **griega***. :) I recommend asking a separate question regarding the Castilian practice of spellings like *doy, voy, estoy, hay, hoy, huy, buey, fray, frey, ley, rey, carey, muy* — as compared with spellings like *fui, ahí, caí, leí, reí, sonreí, huí*. Note also examples like Latin *cu**i**us* (meaning “whose” and also written *cu**j**us* medievally) becoming Spanish *cu**y**o* but Portuguese *cu**j**o*.

Comment: @guifa Dice [este artículo en *El Tiempo*](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-12040950) que “El plural de *gay* en español es *gais”* pero admite que “Con *gais,* plural de *gay,* ha habido mayor resistencia.” También vale la pena leer el último párrafo de [este artículo](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-12062105) en cuanto a todo ello.

Comment: @tchrist Perhaps you know the answer to [this](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18123/13418) then. *Hay* is thought to come from the Old Spanish *ha* (it has) + *i* (there -from the Latin *ibi*) but why do haber's other tenses not have this addition of 'there' to create the 'there was/will be/used to be'?

Comment: @techrist es más una suposición que una afirmación. Sabemos que el castellano de la península y el de otros territorios ha evolucionado de manera diferente por el aislamiento o desafección entre estos territorios. Esto mismo puede aplicarse al periodo de la reconquista. El catalán, gallego, Vasco, etc en comparación al castellano estuvieron en contacto con otras formas del romance por más tiempo (la francesa p.e) mientras que el Castellano estuvo más aislado y más sometido a la influencia del mozárabe (reconquista). No es de extrañar que de entre todas las lenguas de la península...

Comment: sea la única que sufrió cambios como el de la Y. Si buscamos por su origen en latín [Regis](https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/rex#Lat.C3.ADn) nos aparece que es, de entre otras lenguas del romance, la única que ha cambiado la I por la Y.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that *Plaça del Rei* is Catalan, not Spanish (cf. *Pla**z**a del Re**y***).

As for why Catalan *rei* retained a more conservative orthography (given both forms derive from the Latin *regis*), I think this is due to Catalan (among other Romance languages) historically maintaining the influcence of Romance for longer than Castillian.

Castillian, due to its half a millennia politico-economic-military expansion along the peninsula, suffered more changes than Catalan.

It's a poor resume, but 800 years of history is hard to summarize. I suggest taking a look at Wikipedia's [History of Catalan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Catalan)  for further detail.

Comment: OK, that explains it! I presume that the Old Spanish was *rei* and so the equivalent terms in Modern Spanish (rey), Portuguese and Catalan (both rei) are all descendants.

Comment: Both languages come from the Latín so there're lot of words that sounds alike. And also are typed alike.

Comment: **Rey** n. from *10th cent. Old Spanish reie. From Latin regem, accusative of rex 'id.' From Proto-Italic *rēgs 'id.' From Proto-Indo-European *h3rēǵs 'id.'* This is probably the route.